# Cannot upload photo using Transloadit in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, ruby-on-rails-4, transloadit

I followed the tutorial on the [Transloadit Rails GitHub page](https://github.com/transloadit/rails-sdk) but can't get the form to submit without getting an alert: `Could not find input[name=params] in your form`. After I click "ok", Transloadit quickly throws `INVALID_FORM_DATA: bad form data, cannot parse` and the data never hits my server.

My app is using `Rails 4.1.4` and `jquery-rails 2.1.4`.

Here's my form:

```
= form_for @profile, url: community_add_photo_path(@profile), html: {id: 'photo_form'} do |f|
  = render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object
  = transloadit :profile_photo
  = hidden_field_tag 'transloadit_template', 'profile_photo'

  %table.list
    %tr
      %td.faded.label Photo Filename
      %td= f.file_field :photo, required: true
    %tr
      %td
      %td= f.submit 'Upload'

= transloadit_jquerify :photo_form, wait: true
```

And my `transloadit.yml` file:

```
development:
  jquery_sdk_version: 'latest'
  auth:
    key:      'key'
    secret:   'secret'
    duration: 1800 # 30 minute validity period for signed upload forms

  templates:
    profile_photo:
      steps:
        resize:
          height: 256
          resize_strategy: 'fillcrop'
          robot: '/image/resize'
          width: 256
        store:
          bucket: 'bucket-name'
          key: 'key'
          path: 'temp/${assembly.id}/${file.name}'
          robot: '/s3/store'
          secret: 'secret'
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have params decoder in the controller. This is what I have and it works but now going to use jquery because I don't have control over whats going on.

```
        = bootstrap_form_for apr, :remote=> true,   html: { :id => "showapr#{apr.id}" , "data-type" => :json,    class: 'form-horizontal' } do |f|
            = hidden_field_tag :eventid, apr.event.id
            = transloadit :video_encode
            .fileupload.fileupload-new.pull-left{"data-provides" => "fileupload", style: "padding-right: 5px;"}  
                .fileupload-preview.thumbnail{:style => "width: 140px; height: 140px;"}
                    - if apr.upload.present?
                        - if apr.upload["thumbs"].present?
                            %img{ :src => apr.upload["thumbs"][0], :style => "width: 140px;height: 140px;"}
                    -else
                        %img{"data-src" => "holder.js/140x140/text:Lorem ipsum/social", :src => "", :style => "width: 140px;height: 140px;"}/
                - if apr.event.app.check_user_failed == false &&  (apr.event.start_time.day == Time.zone.now.day)
                    %div
                        %span.btn.btn-default.btn-file
                            %span.fileupload-new Select image
                            =f.file_field "upload#{apr.id}" , accept: 'video/flv,video/avi,video/mov,video/mp4,video/mpg,video/wmv,video/3gp,video/asf,video/rm,video/swf',  :data => {:max_file_size => 30.megabytes}
                    = transloadit_jquerify "showapr#{apr.id}", :wait => true, :modal=>true,  :triggerUploadOnFileSelection=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're not actually posting the correct form data to the API so that it can resolve correctly.

https://transloadit.com/docs/api/response-codes/

gives you: NO_PARAMS_FIELD  No params field was given.

Makes perfect sense because you're not passing the params field as well to the API, which you use when you use transloadit's jquery methods

```
params: {
 "startdate":"2014-12-02", 
 "endate":"2014-12-03",
 "auth":{ 
   "expires": "2014/12/27 16:53:14+00:00", 
   "key": "yourKeyValue"
  }
}
&signature=yourUniqueSignature
```

So, something is wrong in how the parameters are created to send to the API for transloadit to work.